# How to make a inner div scroll to bottom after user has scrolled 400px?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a chat application , and when user scrolls to 400px I want an inner div(which contains the chats) and has max-height set to scroll to bottom of that max height.

```
Currently I am using this component in the bottom of that inner div.

    const ScrollBottom = () => {
      const elementRef = useRef(null);
      const [showTopBtn, setShowTopBtn] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        elementRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }, [window?.scrollY === 400]);
      return <div ref={elementRef} />;
    };

export default ScrollBottom;
```

In current scenario , scroll is happening the moment page loads. But I want the scroll to happen only after user has scrolled 400px of page.

Answer (score 0):

Set `window?.scrollY === 400` as `useEffect` dependence will not trigger it to re-run because dependences should only be statefull, you need to add `scroll` event listener to the `window` and check inside if the `scrollY` is more than 400

```
const ScrollBottom = () => {
const elementRef = useRef(null);
const [showTopBtn, setShowTopBtn] = useState(false);

const scrollHandler = () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 400) {
      elementRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
  []);

  return <div ref={elementRef} />;
};

export default ScrollBottom;
```

Comment: I get the logic. But for some reason it is not working in my app. The scroll for inner div is getting triggered only after I have scrolled the page to the bottom and not after 400px.
I checked window.scrollY value and even if it is past 400 , scroll is not getting triggered.